# React rendering components in different html elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, render

I am quite new to ReactJS. I want to have two buttons which toggle the rendering between two components in same div on my page. I started with:

```
class NewComponent1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div {...this.props}>
            new component1
           </div>
        );
    }
}
class NewComponent2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div {...this.props}>
               new component2
           </div>
        );
    }
}
class Button1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <button {...this.props}>
               click1
           </button>
        );
    }  
}
class Button2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <button {...this.props}>
            click2
          </button>
        );
    }  
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          clicked1: false,
          clicked2: false
        };
        this.handleClick1 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
        this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick2.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick1() {
        this.setState({
            clicked1: true,
            clicked2: false
        });
    }
    handleClick2() {
     this.setState({
      clicked2: true,
      clicked1: false
   });
   }
   render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <Button1 onClick={this.handleClick1} />
      <Button2 onClick={this.handleClick2} />
      {this.state.clicked1 ? <NewComponent1 /> : null}
      {this.state.clicked2 ? <NewComponent2 /> : null}
    </div>
  );
  }
  };

  React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

My speculated result is simple. If I press `Button1` I got rendered `MyComponent1` in div with `id="area"` and if press `Button2` I got rendered `MyComponent2` in div with `id="area`", AND `MyComponent1` will not render. And so on. Vice-verse. If `MyComponent1` is present, `MyComponent2` is rendered on page.
Also `Button1` and `Button2` are render permanently in other div with `id="root"`. The toggling should happen only in div with `id="area"`.

Looking forward for some tips ;)

Comment: Sorry... what's your question?

Comment: `state` is *not* static: `App.state`

Comment: How can I render Buttons in one div, and based on clicked button, render conntent in other div ?

Comment: I edited the a code a bit.

Comment: Where are those IDs defined? I can't see any of them. I assume you know that the HTML React generates is going to be inside that element with ID=root, you can't do anything outside of it, that's how React works.

Comment: Yes. Of course. I got two that div in html file as well, inside body tag: 
<body>
<div id="root></div>
</body>